# Can tree branches be cut so low that they will not grow back?

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care

The problem is I had my arbor trimmed too low and I believe it is dead now.

Can the branches be cut so low that they will not grow back?

Comment: Greetings @P. Cov and welcome to G&L SE. Please take the Tour https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour to get familiar how this site works. Regarding to your specific question, adding pictures and providing more information about tree species in your question would greatly help in getting proper answer.

Comment: It depends on what plant species you trimmed. In any case a photo will help.

Comment: There is no way one is able to cut TOO LOW, too close?  Enough to kill a plant.  Perhaps enhance infection, disrupt part of the vascular system.  An arbor is a constructed architectural element like a fence or gate or screen in the landscape.  Vines are usually grown on arbors, pergolas, screens...are you talking about pruning a vine on this arbor?  Did you hire a professional or some land'scraper'?  grins. Pictures, more information, please.

Comment: How long ago was it trimmed back? And did anything else happen that might have killed three?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible.  It's like felling a tree.

Some tree species can resprout from roots or what little bark is left.  Some can't.  Here are some details: https://www.quora.com/Will-a-tree-grow-again-if-only-the-stump-is-left